# OneToMany in Django-Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

Django has the StackedInline-Feature for the Admin-Backend - is there any equivalent for django.forms? When i define a ForeignField representing a ManyToOne-Relation, it does not show up in generated forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin is built exclusively using Django's forms module, so if it's possible in the admin, it's possible outside.

In this case you want inline formsets. See the documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

Comment: great - it works another way than i expected, but works fine. thanks!